# Swift 3: In app purchase functionalities with several items

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I try to implement in-app purchase functionalities with several permanent items in Swift 3 for my spritekit game. Everything is created on iTunes Connect, the bundle name is set and my 4 items are correctly declared in the iTunes Connect. The problem is about code inside Xcode. I use the tutorial from Raywenderlich.com here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

This tutorial is made for just one item, but what about if we need more items ? (4 in my case). I try for 2 days to modify the code to manage more than one single item, without any success. I have modified the structure RageProducts with the following code:

```
import Foundation

public struct RageProducts {

public static let GirlfriendOfDrummerRage = "com.creaworks.FurryLight_Puzzles.Guitarist"



fileprivate static let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = [RageProducts.GirlfriendOfDrummerRage]

// Initial declaration for one item
// public static let store = IAPHelper(productIds: RageProducts.productIdentifiers)
}

//New declaration for 4 items
public static let store = IAPHelper(productIds: Set(
[
  GreenGrocerPurchase.AdRemoval,
  GreenGrocerPurchase.NewShoppingLists_One,
  GreenGrocerPurchase.NewShoppingLists_Five,
  GreenGrocerPurchase.NewShoppingLists_Ten
  ].map { $0.productId }
 ))

func resourceNameForProductIdentifier(_ productIdentifier: String) -> String? {
return productIdentifier.components(separatedBy: ".").last
}
```

When I test the code, the compiler return no error but I see no item in my purchase list (instead of one when I activate the old one item declaration). What am I missing?

Is there a swift 3 simplest code example to declare several items for in app purchase ? I can't find any on the web. I use spritekit, so, I don't need tableview components or UIView buttons, this is a little bit confusing for just starting with in app purchase functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add additional identifiers, similar to this one:

```
public static let GirlfriendOfDrummerRage = "com.creaworks.FurryLight_Puzzles.Guitarist"
```

Then add them to `Set<ProductIdentifier>`.

Here an example with 2 products:

```
public struct Products {

    public static let One = "com.creaworks.FurryLight_Puzzles.Guitarist"
    public static let Two = "com.creaworks.FurryLight_Puzzles.GuitaristTWO"

    fileprivate static let productIndentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = [Products.One, Products.Two]

    func resourceNameForProductIdentifier(_ productIdentifier: String) -> String? {
        return productIdentifier.components(separatedBy: ".").last
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, do I need several IAPHelper instances or can I manage several items with just one instance (the store variable) ?

Comment: Same one. Make sure you use the correct `struct` name

Comment: Great, it works fine, I can see my four items in my list ! in-app purchase are not easy to code if we only know spritekit !